# Android - Merge image files to a movie (but not using JMF)

Tags: android, jmf

I'd like to write an app that merges multiple images into a movie on Android. JMF has a basic implementation ([JpegImagesToMovie](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8AE9208DC5FB846910DFD3F935D64E7C9A5BB784.aspx)). But, JMF isn't supported on Dalvik.

Is there an alternative library that I can use for this ?  Or if there is no library available, does anyone have any pointers for what I need to research to implement myself.

Rgds, Kevin.

Comment: I tried the FMJ (a open source JMF), but it does not work with JpegImagesToMovie. I think the solution is FFMpeg, I will try that now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any pure-Java video encoders, and the built-in video encoder in Android appears to be limited to capturing video from the camera alone, rather than a custom input source.

You could look at writing a multi-part JPEG (quite rare but well supported) writer, or even an MJPEG (used by many digicams) encoder.